# How to fix - TypeError: object StreamReader can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using python(3.8.8) aiohttp and asyncio to make asynchronous http requests.
However, when I try to await a call to **resp.content** I receive the
**TypeError: object StreamReader can't be used in 'await' expression**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_aiohttp.py", line 34, in get_country_wrapper
    country_lst = await asyncio.gather(*result)
  File "test_aiohttp.py", line 17, in get_country
    html_text = await resp.content
TypeError: object StreamReader can't be used in 'await' expression
```

But when I try to await a call to **resp.json()**, it works.

```
async def get_country(session, url):
    '''
        Return the country of a given kaggle user
    '''    
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        # json_resp = await resp.json()
        html_text = await resp.content
        country = re.search(r',"country":"([\w ]+)"', html_text)
        return str(country.group(1))



async def get_country_wrapper(usernames):

    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            
            base_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/'
            result = []
            for username in usernames:
                url = base_url+str(username)
                result.append(asyncio.create_task(get_country(session, url)))

            country_lst = await asyncio.gather(*result)
            return country_lst

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", traceback.format_exc())


# Below is a sample list of users.
# Actual requirement is to run below for about 10,000 or more users
user_list = ['jhovey1', 'jsheppard95', 'dudihgustian', 'khmx5200', 'skshivamkedia']
asyncio.run(get_country_wrapper(user_list[:5]))
```

Why can't I use resp.content like resp.json() here?

(The reason why I am using resp.content instead of resp.json() is latter one gives error for this particular url)

I have referenced below articles where usage of resp.json() in above described.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp

https://itqna.net/questions/76711/error-requests-aiohttp-asyncio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientResponse.json` is a coroutine that tries to parse the response data as JSON and returns a dictionary. `ClientResponse.content` is the `StreamReader` Object user to read the response data. That two aren’t interchangeable. You probably want `ClientResponse.text` which returns the response data as a string or `ClientResponse.bytes` which returns it the response data a bytes.

```
html_text = await resp.text()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dirn.
Now I am getting below error.

`Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001A6C5BCF790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')`

Comment: Any idea on what could be the reason?
Below is the edited code
`async def get_country(session, url):
    '''
        Return the country of a given kaggle user
    '''    
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        html_text = await resp.text()
        country = re.search(r',"country":"([\w ]+)"', html_text)
        if country != None:
            country_ = str(country.group(1))
            print(country_)
            return country_
        else:
            return "NA"
`

Comment: Comments aren’t really the place to share code like this. You’re better off asking a new question. Though I suspect that if you remove the `create_task` calls from the username loop (`result.append(get_country(session, url))`), you’ll get an easier to read error.

Comment: Sorry about that @dirn
Excuse me for that since I am a novice here.
BTW, I found using `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` instead of `asyncio.run(main())` worked around this issue (mentioned in the above comment).